# Elasticsearch - Count of associations between indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Coming from the relational database background, I want to know if there is a way to retrieve the number of unique associations between two indexes.

Basic Example (Using relational databases)

I have 3 tables: Person, Cars, Person-Cars

Person-Cars has two columns (person_id, car_id) and holds the number of associations (ownership) between people and cars.

- On Elasticsearch, I have created an index for Person and for Cars.

**Main Point**

**Everytime that I fetch a Car document, I want to know how many people own that car (IOW how many associations it has to unique people)**

--

To archieve that, I would need another index for Person-Cars, and then would have to index all the association records? Is there a simpler way? What would be the best way to do this in ES?

I have looked into aggregations, but I think that can only be done on a single level (person or cars) not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Elastic is not a relational database. You would use a separate query to the person index counting the number of occurances (terms agg) for the given car model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On Elasticsearch, I have created an index for Person and for Cars.

Most of the times it makes sense to store the data in a denormalized fashion in elastic search, viz defining one-to-many relationships as either [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/nested.html) or [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) relationship or simply in multi-value fields.

> What would be the best way to do this in ES?

It depends on your use case (either parent-child or nested or multi-value). Having separate indexes for each type definitely will add overhead. If you add other use cases and type of queries which you would be needing then only schema can be better modelled.

**Considering only the shared use case:** Below car document will solve your case :

```
{
  "id":1,
  "brand":"Hyundai",
  "owners":[21,31,51] // <===== Ids of owners. Ids & names both can be stored if required.
  "owners_cnt": 3 // <==== OR You can simply maintain the counter as well.
}
```

Whenever a person buy/sell a car, then car document needs to updated in this case. If buying and selling of cars happens frequently and you need to update both car & person if a person bought a car then this type of modelling makes less sense.

In that case it makes sense to have car_ids within-person doc :

{
"id":1,
"name":"Raj",
"cars":[1,2,3]
}

In this case, we can use below query to fetch the number of persons who bought a car , having id=3

```
GET person/_count
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "cars": 3
        }
      }
```

Again better modelling can be achieved if more context is shared.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and time @Sahil Gupta, My actual use case will have an index page which will feature many cars (100+), and alongside each car will show the number of people associated with it. I am afraid that doing a `_count` for each car may ruin the performance, and storing the count could also greatly increase the indexing time. My actual use case is not cars and person, the ideia is the same, but the volume of data is really big, and thats why I am concerned.  But I guess doing the `_count` query should be the best way

Comment: If you need to show a list of cars and for each car, you need to show the number of people who bought this car. And If count(reads) is way more than count(person buying/selling cars) then it makes sense to have owner_ids in car document.

Comment: Do you think it could hurt the ES performance for indexing/retrieving, if the list of person ids on cars could go beyond millions, hundred thousands?

Comment: For a very popular car - owned by millions, need to check. However we can tweak the refresh interval, which will make reads eventually consistent and indexing cost will be reduced